# iOS BluetoothLE: CBCentralManager Unsubscribes From Updates

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I have a mac set up as a bluetooth accessory using CoreBluetooth as a `CBPeripheralManager`. The Mac is advertising on a set characteristic `CBUUID`, and once it has a subscriber, I click a button to stream a UTF-8-encoded time stamp every half second.

I have an iPhone set up as a `CBCentralManager` subscribing to the appropriate characteristic. I update the iPhone's UI with the decoded timestamp every time it receives the data and the app is active. The `bluetooth-central` background mode is set in the `.plist` file.

The iPhone continues to debug print and update the UI for the timestamps for about 25 seconds, then just stops. This happens whether the app is in the foreground or the background. **EDIT:** The `CBPeripheralManager` receives an `didUnsubscribeFrom characteristic` callback at this time. I don't see any reason `didUnsubscribeFrom` would be called, no idea why it's always after 25 seconds.

The `CBPeripheralManager` continues to merrily send its time stamps. The return value from the `CBPeripheralManager`'s `updateData(_:for:onSubscribedCentrals:)` call is always true, indicating that the queue never is full.

There's a lot of code involved here, showing the most relevant.

From the `CBCentralManager` app:

```
 func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
     print(central.state.rawValue)
     centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [timeUUID], options: nil)
     print("scanning")
 }

 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
     peripheral.delegate = self
     peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

     print("connected")
 }

 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
     print(peripheral.name as Any)
     print(advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] as! Array<CBUUID>)
     self.peripheralController = peripheral

     self.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
 }

 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    if service.uuid.uuidString == timeUUID.uuidString {
        peripheralController.setNotifyValue(true, for: service.characteristics!.first!)
        peripheralController.readValue(for: service.characteristics!.first!) // EDIT: This was the offending line
    }
 }

 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == timeUUID.uuidString {
        if let valueFrom = characteristic.value  {
            if let this = String(data: valueFrom, encoding: .utf8) {
                if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
                    label.text = this
                    print("ACTIVE \(this)")
                } else if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
                    print("BACKGROUND \(this)")
                } else if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {
                    print("INACTIVE \(this)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

From the `CBPeripheralManager` app:

```
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    myCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: myServiceUUID, properties: [CBCharacteristicProperties.read, CBCharacteristicProperties.notify], value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.readable)
    let myService = CBMutableService(type: myServiceUUID, primary: true)
    myService.characteristics = [myCharacteristic]
    bluetoothController.add(myService)
}

func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeTo characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    print(characteristic.uuid)
    subscriber = central
}

func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didUnsubscribeFrom characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    print(characteristic)
    print("unsubscribe")
}

func repeatAdvertisement() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { [unowned self] (timerRef) in
        guard let maybeTimer = self.timer, maybeTimer.isValid else { return }
        let datum = Date()
        let stringFromDate = self.dateFormatter.string(from: datum)
        let data = stringFromDate.data(using: .utf8)
        print(data!.count)
        //        myCharacteristic.value = data
        let myService = CBMutableService(type: self.myServiceUUID, primary: true)
        myService.characteristics = [self.myCharacteristic]
        let did = self.bluetoothController.updateValue(data!, for: self.myCharacteristic as! CBMutableCharacteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: [self.subscriber])
        print("timed \(stringFromDate) \(did)")
    }


}


func advertise() {
    if timer == nil {
        repeatAdvertisement()
    } else {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

Let me know anything else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for heaven's sake. The issue was the line `peripheralController.readValue(for: service.characteristics!.first!)` I had that line in the app based on some sample code and, well, it was unnecessary.

Apparently the call to `readValue(for:)` causes some sort of timeout. I edited that line out of the app and it happily updates on and on.

Leaving the question up and adding this answer in case anyone ends up facing the same thing someday.